# Issues with Firebase Indexing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a chat app with firebase. Recently I'm getting some problems with the database. In group chat I use `.push()` firebase method to add messages one by one. But from some days it's behaving something strange. Like after sending a message, it displays at last. But after some seconds it moves 500+ rank back. I don't know where is the problem.

I'm not using any index in rules,

```
"groupchat":{
      "$chatid":{
        "chat":{


            ".read" : "root.child('groupmembers').child($chatid).child('members').child(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()).exists()",
          ".write" : "root.child('groupmembers').child($chatid).child('members').child(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val()).exists()",


        }
}
}
```

Don't know if I'm getting this issue due to that or not

Also My Message Structure is like the following

[image: Message Structure]

Android Code to add message,

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        map.put("username", Fusername);
                        map.put("message", message);
                        map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                        map.put("type", "text");
                        map.put("zread", false);
                        chatRef.child("chat").child(chat_key).updateChildren(map);
```

And that problem doesnt occcur everytime. Also, sometimes when a user sends a message, It stays at top due to its pushed key which are sent after it stays before the old message..

Everything was working fine when there were less messages. But now it's behaving so weird. I need help .... THANKS

Comment: Put the code of the recycler view and how are you assigning it

Comment: it's not recyclerview problem. it's happening in the database @MartinDeSimone

Comment: "after some seconds it moves" explain mr how could that happen in db, data is there or it isnt, it cant move

Comment: No problem, here is my adapter class. https://pastebin.com/BjbrnBQG

Comment: Also that problem doesnt occcur everytime. Also sometimes when a user sends a message, It stays at top due to its pushed key. And all new messages stays before it